# How to escape quote when retrieving record from database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I add records to my database using `$wpdb` like this:

```
$title = 'test url';
$content = '<a href="#">test</a>'
$wpdb->insert($db_name, array(
   "title" => $title,
   "content" => $content
), '%s');
```

when i check database i see that content is take the backslash escaping quotes like this: `<a href=\"#\">test</a>`

i have tried to get record from database with `stripcslashes()` but dosnt work.

Is there a way to do so and garding the security reason?

Comment: Using stripcslashes should work unless there are three or more slashes in the string.  Could you possibly have saved the record in such a way that something like '<a href=\\\"#\\\">test</a> is in the database?  Maybe you've updated the same record with itself multiple times?

Comment: @ethan : no, actually it is a google adsense script that is stocked in the database: `<script async src=\"//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script>
<!-- First_Moular_Sidebar2 -->
<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"
     style=\"display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px\"
     data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-xxxxxxxx\"
     data-ad-slot=\"xxxxxxxxxx\"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please get the record from the database and pass it to this function

```
$without_slashes = stripslashes($row['coln']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$title = 'test url';
$content = "'<a href=\"#\">test</a>'"
$wpdb->insert($db_name, array(
   "title" => $title,
   "content" => $content
), '%s');
```

Comment: this will record: `\'<a href=\\\"#\\\">test</a>\'` and the problem described in the question is about how to escap when retrieving not when recording.